# Connecting to docker-engine on remote mac using docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have a MacMini that is sitting in the server room which has a [docker for mac](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-for-mac/install/) running on it.  I'm able to use docker directly on the machine when I ssh in just fine.

```
$ docker --version                                                                                                  
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
```

But I would like to connect to the mac minis docker engine from my own computer using `docker-machine`.  I have tried the following command to create the `docker-machine`.

```
docker-machine create -d generic \
--generic-ip-address 10.0.0.0 \
--generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/mysshkey \
--generic-ssh-user myusername \
--generic-ssh-port 22 \
macmini
```

Error Messages:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(macmini) Importing SSH key...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Error getting SSH command: ssh command error:
command : cat /etc/os-release
err     : exit status 1
output  : cat: /etc/os-release: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone been able to connect remotely to docker-engine running MacOS Catalina using `docker-machine`?  Any tips or pointers would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Docker for Mac can't accept incoming connections.

from https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers

> I cannot ping my containers
>
> Docker Desktop for Mac can’t route traffic to containers.